# Perl File::Temp, file name not random

Tags: perl, mod-perl, temporary-files

I have a strange problem using `File::Temp`:

I am running my perl script under mod_perl in Apache on Linux, Apache is running with worker mpm.

```
my ($fh_error, $error)
    = tempfile("error_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",DIR => "/home/tmp", UNLINK => 1);
my ($fh_src, $src) 
    = tempfile("src_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",DIR => "/home/tmp", UNLINK => 1, SUFFIX => ".html");          
my ($fh_dst, $dst) 
    = tempfile("dst_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",DIR => "/home/tmp", UNLINK => 1, SUFFIX => ".html");
```

Most of the time, everything seems to be ok, but every now or then I get some bad file names.
Instead of getting a true random file name, I get the same letter for all the template length.

for example

```
error_AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
src_AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
dst_AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

All 3 files get the same name.
Except of this just being strange (and you never want your code being strange), I'm afraid this may result in reading/writing to the same file for different from different requests.

Comment: A guess: maybe you ran out of entropy? Do you have munin (or something similar) running on the system and do you see something suspicious in the "available entropy" graph?

Comment: damn haven't even thought of that, it is a bit low right now 100-200

Comment: Yeah, but even with zero entropy, `/dev/urandom` should still continue to give good pseudo-random numbers.  They just wouldn't be cryptographically strong (ie. with N consecutive random numbers you could theoretically work out better odds for what N+1 might be, for a large enough N).

Answer (score 3):

I looked at the source for `File::Temp`.  It replaces the Xs in the template with this concise bit of perl:

```
    $path =~ s/X(?=X*$end)/$CHARS[ int( rand( @CHARS ) ) ]/ge;
```

That uses perl's built-in `rand`, which is just a traditional seed-based random number generator.  That `rand` function is not cryptographically secure.  Its seed is also 'global state', which can lead to problems when forking, as described here:

http://blogs.perl.org/users/brian_phillips/2010/06/when-rand-isnt-random.html

The jist of it is:  If you fork two perl interpreters, and the original interpreter was already seeded by a single call to `rand`, both inherit the same seed after the `fork`, so both will generate the same random number sequence from that point.  Ooops.  So, you may want to call `srand` one in your module before calling `tempfile` or anything else that calls `rand`.

That said, it appears `File::Temp` takes great pains to detect and avoid collisions, but it will give up at some point.  The following warning is buried in the `File::Temp` docs:

```
    If you are forking many processes in parallel that are all creating 
    temporary files, you may need to reset the random number seed using 
    srand(EXPR) in each child else all the children will attempt to walk 
    through the same set of random file names and may well cause themselves 
    to give up if they exceed the number of retry attempts.
```

Comment: I did some digging myself and found out about this problem as well, i also found a suggestion to add `PerlChildInitHandler sub { srand }` to apache conf, but it didn't seem to work